# How to exclude one "column" in .ToListAsync() using EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have this `return` code from an `async` function:

```
return await _context.Models.ToListAsync();
```

That is successful in returning this:

```
[
    { 
        "id":"id",
        "name":"name",
        "url":"url",
        "components":[]
    }
]
```

Now, I want NOT to show the `components` like this.

```
[
    { 
        "id":"id",
        "name":"name",
        "url":"url"
    }
]
```

So far, I tried:

```
return await _context.Models.Select( p => new Model {
    Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, Url = p.Url 
}).ToListAsync();
```

But it will still show `components` and only do nullify its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you create a new model and event if you don't provide the value the compiler gives it the default value.so you need to either create a new class and remove the property from it or you need to populate it dynamically and change your code to something like this:

```
return await _context.Models.Select( p => new {
    Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, Url = p.Url 
}).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks. But same with @Salah, it returns `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Id, string Name, string Url>>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'`

Comment: @CodeRed, you need to change your action result type from Model to object

Answer (score 0):

you should create new model class (DTO) :

```
public class Model2
{
public int Id {get;set};
public string Name {get;set};
public string Url {get;set};
}
```

then use

```
 p => new Model2 {
    Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, Url = p.Url 
}).toListAsync
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use anonymous types like this:

```
return await _context.Models                    
                 .Select(p => new {
                     p.Id,
                     p.Name        
                 });
```

Or create a DTO with all the properties you need except the components property.

```
public class DTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
.Select(p => new DTO {
               Id = p.Id,
               Name = p.Name,
               Url = p.Url
           });
```

Comment: the first one returns `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Id, string Name, string Url>>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult'`

Comment: @CodeRed `Select new { ... }` will just create an anonymous type which can´t be converted to anything except object. So if you still want to use the anonymous version you need to change the type to object. I'd prefer the DTO version though!

Comment: I actually tried DTO version but it will still return another `cannot implicitly convert type...` and changing my `ActionResult` type from `Model` to `object` worked. Thanks tho!

Comment: @CodeRed You need to change to object in both versions to get rid the error. But I'd prefer the DTO version as a cleaner way to do this.